# Regular expression in python doesn't seem to be working like I expect

Tags: python, regex

My code doesn't seem to be working like it's supposed to:

```
x = "engniu4nwi5u"
print re.sub(r"\D(\d)\D", r"\1abc", x)
```

My desired output is: `engniuabcnwiabcu`
But the output actually given is: `engni4abcw5abc`

Comment: As an additional hint: The website https://regex101.com/#python can be very helpful when you are having problems with your regular expressions. Also note the "substitution" slider ab the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grouping the wrong characters it must be written as

```
>>> x = "engniu4nwi5u"
>>> re.sub(r"(\D)\d(\D)", r"\1abc\2", x)
'engniuabcnwiabcu'
```

- `(\D)` Matches a non digit and captures it in `\1`
- `\d` Matches the digit
- `(\D)` Matches the following digit. captures in `\2`

**How does it matches?**

```
engniu4nwi5u
     |
    \D => \1

engniu4nwi5u
      |
     \d

engniu4nwi5u
       |
      \D => \2
```

**Another Solution**

You can also use look arounds to perform the same as

```
>>> x = "engniu4nwi5u"
>>> re.sub(r"(?<=\D)\d(?=\D)", r"abc", x)
'engniuabcnwiabcu'
```

- `(?<=\D)` Look behind assertion. Checks if the digit is presceded by a non digit. But not caputred
- `\d` Matches the digit
- `(?=\D)` Look ahead assertion. Checks if the digit is followed by the non digit. Also not captured.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you replaced the wrong part:

Let's consider the first match. `\D\d\D` matches the following:

```
engniu4nwi5u
     ^^^
```

`4` is captured as `\1`. Then you replace the *whole match* with: `\1abc`, which becomes `4abc`.

You have a couple solutions here:

- Capture what you want to keep: `(\D)\d(\D)` and replace it with `\1abc\2`
- Use lookaheads: `(?<=\D)\d(?=\D)` and replace this with `abc`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your regexp:

```
>>> re.sub("(\D)\d", r"\1abc", x)
'engniuabcnwiabcu'
```

Although I would do this instead:

```
>>> re.sub("\d", "abc", x)
'engniuabcnwiabcu'
```

Comment: Maybe OP wants only digits surrounded by non-digits. Also in your answer, no need for `\1` and capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to check also the beginning and end of string, you need to add `^` and `$` to the regex:

```
(\D|^)\d(?=$|\D)
```

And replace with `\1abc`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wV4wX5/2)

[Sample code on IDEONE](http://ideone.com/2IfhIZ):

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\D|^)\d(?=$|\D)')
test_str = u"1engniu4nwi5u"
subst = u"\1abc"
print re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: Please note that neither `(?<=\D)\d(?=\D)`, nor `(\D)\d(\D)` will match at the beginning of the string.